# gulp-uncss with height equalizer in Zurb Foundation

Tags: zurb-foundation, gulp, gulp-uncss

I'm trying to use `gulp-uncss` to remove unneeded CSS from a [Zurb Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/) website.

Within the site I'm using Foundation's [Equalizer](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/equalizer.html) to make two columns the same height. This works by adding a `data-` attribute to an element:

```
<div data-equalizer>
  <div data-equalizer-watch>
  <div>
  <div data-equalizer-watch>
  <div>
<div>
```

When the page loads Foundation determines the height of the two elements and injects an inline style to set the height of the elements to the greater of the two element heights. The result is:

```
<div data-equalizer>
  <div data-equalizer-watch style="height: 256px;">
  <div>
  <div data-equalizer-watch style="height: 256px;">
  <div>
<div>
```

When I add `gulp-uncss` to my gulpfile.js the Equalizer no longer works. The `data-` attributes are still present in the HTML file, but the inline styles are not added.

I've tried using the `ignore` option in `gulp-uncss` to ignore `height` but had no luck. The inline style is no longer added to HTML document.

Is there an option in `gulp-uncss` that will allow the equalizer to do it's job?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get `gulp-uncss` working using the `ignore` parameter in `UnCSS`.

Adding:

```
ignore: [/^meta.foundation/, /f-topbar-fixed/, /contain-to-grid/, /sticky/, /fixed/]
```

to `uncss()` kept all the necessary CSS. The most important of these is `/^meta.foundation` as this allows the Foundation JS to inject the styles. The remaining values `/f-topbar-fixed`, `contain-to-grid`, `/sticky/` and `/fixed/` are all specific to the Foundation JS modules I'm using. The above work for a `.sticky` topbar.

If you're using other JS modules you'll need to determine what classes are being injected and add those to the the `ignore` array.